# C++ Indexing TCHAR string

Tags: c++, tchar

I am doing some static analysis work on some old C++ code and my C++ is not the strongest. I have this piece of code:

```
void NIDP_clDPLogger::log(TCHAR *logString)
{
    TCHAR temp_logString[1024] = {0};
    _tcsncpy(temp_logString,logString,1024);
    temp_logString[1023] = NULL;
            ...
```

The static analysis tool is complaining here of indexing **logString** (the parameter passed in to function) at 1024 when it may be shorter (the size varies, 1024 is the max. size I guess). So I guess my fix is to check the size of **logString** and use that, like this:

```
void NIDP_clDPLogger::log(TCHAR *logString)
{

    size_t tempSize = sizeof(logString);
    TCHAR temp_logString[tempSize] = {0};
    _tcsncpy(temp_logString,logString,tempSize);
    temp_logString[tempSize-1] = NULL;
```

I am just wondering, will this work OK? Can anybody see any flaws/problems? Building and testing this project is slightly difficult so I am basically just looking for a sanity check before I go through all that. Or is there a better way for me to do it? Can I pass a size_t value in to _tcsncpy, because a hardcoded int was there before?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(logString)` will return the size of a `TCHAR*`, not the size of the array passed as arrays decay to pointers when passed as argument.

If it is guaranteed that `logString` is null terminated you could obtain its length using `_tcslen()`. Otherwise, the only way to know the size of `logString` is to pass it into the function as another argument.

Comment: OK Thanks a million for that hmjd!